# Install Windows 8.1 on a tablet with only a touchscreen, no keyboard or mouse

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, windows-installation, touchscreen

Trying to re-install Windows 8.1 on Acer Iconia W4-820 Tablet. When I boot from a USB and get to the [setup screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkS92.jpg) I notice that I can't use the touchscreen.

I'm guessing it's probably because touchscreen drivers aren't loaded in that setup environment yet? If so, is there a way to make a customized install in which it loads touchscreen driver during the setup phase?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Acer Iconia W4-820 has a micro-USB port (per http://www.cnet.com/products/acer-iconia-w4/), plug in a keyboard and mouse, using a USB hub and adapter or something like this [hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FGKXY9S), which might (or might not) fit your tablet.